# Open app on device startup

Tags: automation, auto-start, web-server

I have a cheap android tablet that I want to use behind some 2 way glass. So I want it to display a webpage on startup. If possible it would be better if it also could run a webserver with PHP, msql and similar. As the tablet would be behind glass there would be no need for it to do anything else. 
I guess I could have it using some sort of camera activity on face recognition, or movement detection. These would be extra features.for a later date

Comment: What have you searched and found that doesn't work?  I have found the following https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gears42.surelock&hl=en

Comment: I would prefer to open applications for free. Also as I want to show info on my mirror so I will not want to see any other furniture, i thought i could just show a "full screen / f11" with a web browser and have bright colored text (to show through the mirror) and black background to show the mirror.

Comment: this might work https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/full-screen-252573/

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Have you already checked with our other [kiosk-mode questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kiosk-mode)?

Comment: What's your actual question?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're actually asking - "Open an app on startup" - then Tasker should be able to handle this pretty easily.

Get Tasker from [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) (it does cost £2.99 for the app. For me, it was well worth it as its a very powerful tool. I guess it depends if you would get any other use out of it). You then need to create a *Profile* (the context of the device at a particular time) and a *Task* (what you want the device to do).

**Create a profile to run the task on device boot;**

`Profiles tab > Add new profile (+ button) > Event > System > Device Boot`

**Create a new task (it should prompt you to do this);**

`Add a new action (+ button) > Net > Browse URL > enter the URL`

Comment: This post does not contain enough information to be considered an answer. How did it solve the issue? Where to find it? What are the steps to perform?